# UICollectionView cannot display customized cell content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to create a dummy photo app with UICollectionView. My Xcode version is 7.2 and Swift version 2.1.1. I use [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXyzo.png) to build the UI part by following the tutorial from http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

In Swift 2.0, the **UICollectionViewDataSource** is inherited from **UICollectionViewController**, we don't need to explicitly declare those protocols. I implemented the required override methods for DataSource, and also register the customized cell in **viewDidLoad()** in the **UICollectionViewController**. I put a test **Label** in my cell to check whether it works or not. Unfortunately, the label never appear after I launch the app. I attach some of my code below as reference:

**UICollectionViewController**

```
class VacationsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private let reuseIdentifier = "VacationCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(VacationsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VacationsCollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        cell.CellText.text = "Show me the money"

        return cell
    }
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
class VacationsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var CellText: UILabel!
}
```

Any idea why the label never show up in my dummy app?

Comment: In your storyboard, select your `UICollectionViewCell` and open the _Attributes inspector_. Make sure that you've entered `VacationCell` in the field _Identifier_.

Comment: @dfri Yes, the _identifier_ is there with value `VacationCell`. Thanks for the reminder though, it is an easy one to forget.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything you need. The issue is probably with your storyboard. Just to be safe, add constraints to the label so it's definitely going to be displayed properly. Then, add an extension to your collection view controller and be sure the size allows the label to be displayed as well. This, at least, worked for me and I was in your exact situation.

```
extension OfficesCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally decided to switch to UITableView with exactly the same logic, and that works. Thanks for the answer.